# Vim setup of Lars

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program

I was wondering which Vim setup Lars uses in his video, is this perhaps natively available when we use the nix-shell? In lecture two of the third cohort his vim suggests what I guess common used functions, what plugin is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we can't give exact definition of Lars' Vim configuration, but regarding the [intelligent code completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_code_completion), there are many Vim add-ons that achieve this. [coc](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) and [Vim Intellisense](http://insenvim.sourceforge.net/) are two examples.

If you're keen on modding your Vim configuration, you could also check [Neovim](https://neovim.io/), which is a fork that "strives to improve the extensibility and maintainability of Vim".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [this](https://docs.plutus-community.com/docs/setup/editors/vim.html). After following this guide and setting up the plugins, you will need to `nix-shell` inside plutus-apps, and then `cabal update` and `cabal build` inside the actual haskell code you are trying to use (as Lars explained in the first lecture). That's it, now you can use vim to open your file and, after some time, you will see some cool little colors.

By the way I suggest neovim, because with vim you don't have any idea of what's going on while haskell-language-server is still loading (also neovim is cooler)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a language server protocol setup (i.e. `haskell-language-server`). Basically the same as VSCode, but with a different client.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).