# How can I configure Ale so it finds Plutus libraries?

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, haskell

I'm using nvim with Ale, no particular config other than:

```
Plug 'w0rp/ale'
let g:ale_sign_error = '●'
let g:ale_sign_warning = '●'
```

It looks like works out of the box for Haskell, but cannot find Plutus libraries:

```
$ nvim src/Week02/Gift.hs
```

[image]

```
:messages

Could not find module ‘Plutus.Contract’ Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for. |16 | import           Plutus.Contract | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                                                            
Could not find module ‘PlutusTx’ Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for. |17 | import           PlutusTx            (Data (..)) | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                                   
Could not find module ‘PlutusTx’ Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for. |18 | import qualified PlutusTx | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                                                                                 
Could not find module ‘PlutusTx.Builtins’ Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for. |19 | import qualified PlutusTx.Builtins   as Builtins | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                          
Could not find module ‘PlutusTx.Prelude’ Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for. |20 | import           PlutusTx.Prelude    hiding (Semigroup(..), unless) | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                     
Could not find module ‘Ledger’ Perhaps you meant Lexer (needs flag -package-key ghc-8.10.4.20210212) Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for. |21 | import           Ledger              hiding (singleton) | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
...
```

Any idea how to configure Ale so it finds Plutus libraries?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vim setup of Lars](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/6679/vim-setup-of-lars)

Comment: Not really, no reference to Ale at all in there.